# email validation on client side failing in asp.net mvc (not validating dot requirement after @ symbol)

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a following javascript in my asp.net mvc code

```
var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                        if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
                            document.getElementById("usererror").textContent = 'Please Enter Valid Email';
                            email.focus();
                            return false;
                        }
```

Validation is working fine other then it doesn't check dot requirement after @ symbol. Please help me in correcting the regular expression.

Answer:
Now using following pattern in my mvc form

```
var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
```

Comment: Escape the dot.

Comment: Can you please post it as answer with updated pattern

Comment: The question has been closed, so no, sorry :(

Comment: It's in the context of asp.net mvc where we needed to escape @ character. @Wiktor Stribiżew On Stackoverflow nowadays effort are mostly done for closing, deleting the question rather then to answering it.

Comment: You mean /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot @FedericoklezCulloca